# C# WPF Button Styles inside DLL

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, dll, styles

I'm making a DLL for me, to ease my job, because there are classes that I use in every project, so why should i duplicate them, when I can use one DLL to finish the job,

I also wanted to add some controls to it, buttons, so its like this:

I have created a button, and it works well, but I want to add a custom style to it, to disable the background highlighting when you are mouse over, now i have used this style before and works well, but in previous times, I would add the style to the app.xaml resources and then set the style to the button like:

> Style="{StaticResource DisableBackgroundHighlight}"

but since the DLL does not have app.xaml, what should I do, how to add style to the control inside the DLL?
All I've found on google was, to reference the resources from the DLL to the app.xaml of the WPF app, but thats not what I want, 
I tried this:

```
<Button x:Class="SRX.Windows.Controls.SRXButton"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SRX.Windows.Controls"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="35" d:DesignWidth="100" Content="OK" Background="White" BorderBrush="Blue" Foreground="Blue" MouseEnter="Button_MouseEnter" MouseLeave="Button_MouseLeave" Style="{StaticResource DisableBackgroundHighlight}">
<Button.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="DisableBackgroundHighlight" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True" />
        <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Border Name="border" BorderThickness="0" BorderBrush="Black" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.8" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Button.Resources>
```

but it doesnt work, it shows "The resource "DisableBackgroundHighlight" could not be resolved." altough it compiles but crashes on startup.
If I missed something in the problem explanation please ask me to resolve, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Simply add a xaml file to your project. Let's call it Generic.xaml which is where usually the templates for your custom coltrols will be located .

This file will have the following format:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:Themes="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Themes;assembly=PresentationFramework.Aero"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    x:Class="Your.Domain.Generic">
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="whatever else you defined in another xaml"/>        
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <Style TargetType="TextBox" ....
</ResourceDictionary>
```

on the other assemblies, you import your "style" assembly just like anything else:

```
xmlns:style="clr-namespace:Your.Domain.Shared"
```

Supposing of course that you style assembly is named Your.Domain.Shared